# Does anyone know of any cross platform GUI log viewers for Ruby On Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, user-interface, logging

I'm tired of using:

```
tail -f development.log
```

To keep track of my rails logs. Instead I would like something that displays the info in a grid and allows my to sort, filter and look at stack traces per log message.

Does anyone know of a GUI tool for displaying rails logs. Ideally I would like a standalone app (not something in Netbeans or Eclipse)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FWIW I started [this project](http://github.com/SamSaffron/logviewer/tree/master) at GitHub to try and solve this problem, its far from functional.

Answer (score 1):

Splunk, there is a Free version that is limited to 500mb but has all the same functionality as the full version.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use http://logging.apache.org/chainsaw/index.html . Haven't used it in a long time but I think its log parser should be configurable

Comment: not sure about this one, it looks pretty primitive ... will give it a shot

Answer (score 0):

I like using the Exception Logger plugin for live sites.  I can visit http://domain.com/logged_exceptions, and read all of the unhandled exceptions that have been throw in production, along with full stack traces.  From there, it's pretty easy to write tests to find and correct the problem.  There's a whole railscast on the topic [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/104).

Answer (score 0):

I asked the same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/144807/java-log-viewer) a few days ago and got suggestions for Splunk, BareTail, and tail [been using Chainsaw until now].

Chainsaw didn't work so well for me. It was buggy and non-responsive. So I looked into Splunk which turned out to be a big overkill for just viewing logs. Tail seemed a bit too primitive for my taste. So if you're on Windows, I'd say BareTail is your best bet.

HTH