# Log file viewer needed with web interface

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, logging, log4j

I need a log file viewer with a method of allowing access to a software tester. The tester does not have access to the server, and has reduced user priviledges. Thus I belive the best way would be adding some sort of web interface based log file viewer. The development language is java and the server is a Java EE server (Geronimo).

A war that I could install and configure to point to the log would be an awesome solution. Open Source/free only.

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/144807/java-log-viewer

Comment: I have seen this before asking. I need a solution that is web based ideally. due to network topology restraints

Answer (score 2, accepted):

log2web?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log4j#Log_viewers

Comment: Good Answer! - shame it doesnt install. Still in Beta.

Comment: how about SawMill, XpoLog, XLog-Solution mentioned on wikipedia?